# How to get base URL in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I just want to get the URL path upto the cfm page. For example if my URL is like `http://125.145.23.65/test/login.cfm` I need it as `http://125.145.23.65/test/`

If URL is like `https://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm` i need upto `https://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator/`

How to obtain this?

Comment: Treat it as a `/` delimited list.  Then read this.  https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/listdeleteat.html

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind, if the site is behind a load balancer doing SSL off-loading, the value of `SERVER_PORT_SECURE` will be `0`. In that case, there may be other headers the load balancer writes, `CGI.X_FORWARDED_PROTO`, etc.

These are somewhat standard, but it's a bit vendor dependent.

X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Proto, X-Forwarded-Port

```
<cfscript>
baseUrl='http#iif(CGI.SERVER_PORT_SECURE,"s","")#://#CGI.SERVER_NAME##getDirectoryFromPath(cgi.SCRIPT_NAME)#';
writeOutput(baseUrl);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: nice, a much cleaner way than the mess i came up with!

Comment: Might also use the ternary operator. It's a little slicker than iif. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-expressions-and-number-signs/expressions-developing-guide.html

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try.

```
<cfset varUrl = cgi.request_url>
<cfset varUrlArr = listToArray(varUrl,'/')>
<cfset x = arrayDeleteAt(varUrlArr, len(varUrlArr))>
<cfset varNewUrl = arrayToList(varUrlArr,'/')>
<cfdump var="#varNewUrl#/">
```

Comment: `getDirectoryFromPath(CGI.request_url)` would work too

Answer (score 1):

theres probably a better way to do this, but in the cgi scope SCRIPT_NAME and HTTP_URL would give you /test/login.cfm, HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME would give you 125.145.23.65. if you treat SCRIPT_NAME or HTTP_URL as a list with the / as the delimiter as dan said, this

```
<cfoutput>#cgi.server_name##Replace(cgi.script_name,ListLast(cgi.script_name, "/"),"")#</cfoutput>
```

would give you;

```
125.145.23.65/test/
```

update:

so, following dan's comments and using ListDeleteAt, you can use;

```
<cfoutput>#cgi.server_name##ListDeleteAt(cgi.script_name,ListLen(cgi.script_name,"/"),"/")#/</cfoutput>
```

if you need to know if its http or https SERVER_PROTOCOL will tell you

Comment: I would have used `listDeleteAt` myself, but there is always more than one way to accomplish something.  By the way, I think you made a mistake in your replace function.

Comment: this is giving me 125.145.23.65/test/all/

Comment: @DanBracuk i didn't even know there was a listdeleteat - thanks, good to know :) and you're right, i did make a mistake - i'll fix it. i think i shouldn't answer questions in future, i do more harm than good!

Comment: Keep answering questions.  While my actual motivation to do so it recreation, there is a professional development bonus that comes from reading other people's answers.

Comment: @DanBracuk i don't post much, but i love reading others posts - i've learnt a lot from here. i've updated my post and tried the listDeleteAt

Answer (score 0):

This UDF written by Steven Levithan is very good at breaking up URL/URI into the respective components which you could then recombine into what you need.

http://badassery.blogspot.com/2007/01/parsing-uris-in-coldfusion.html

Answer (score 0):

I do something like the below to store the url sections in an array for later parsing. Breadcrumbs, etc.

```
<!--- IIS7+ --->
<cfif CGI.HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL neq ''>
    <cfset request.urlStrings= listToArray(spanExcluding(CGI.HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL,"?"), "/")>
</cfif>
<!--- ISAPI_rewrite --->
<cfif CGI.HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL neq ''>
    <cfset request.urlStrings= listToArray(spanExcluding(CGI.HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL ,"?"), "/")>
</cfif>
```

So if you only want the first directory in the URL, it would be `#request.urlstrings[1]#`.

You can then include the protocol and server name:

```
#getPageContext().getRequest().getScheme()#://#cgi.server_name#/#request.urlstrings[1]#
```